# Does Cochin (COK, India) airport have free Wi-Fi?

Tags: airports, india, wifi

I will be landing at Cochin airport (COK) and will need to get Uber without having Indian SIM (which is apparently pain to get and takes time to activate).

Does Cochin airport have Wi-Fi?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you do have free Wi-fi at Cochin airport. The [Cochin airport website](http://cial.aero/contents/viewcontent.aspx?linkIdLvl2=88&linkId=88) states that there is Wi-fi at the airport. However, you can only connect if you have access to the local mobile number. You need to provide the OTP for signing up.

The last time I checked was in February and I was unable to use my German number for authentication. They do claim that the authentication should work for international numbers but it never worked for me. You can always go to the helpdesk and ask for assistance. Generally, the agent would help you in getting the temporary OTP (worked for me several times).

Answer (score 4):

As of July 2019, at the Intl Terminal,  **the Wifi is FREE, available for Passengers only** -- after they complete the Security and wait at gates. 
There is a wi-fi desk which helps all irrespective of the cellphone SIM they have, to get their OTPS and use the wifi.

Comment: That sounds like a service for departing passengers whereas the OP is arriving. Can you edit to clarify?